# PHP openstreetmap lineDash does not take array variable

Tags: php, arrays

In the code below i try to assign a value to lineDash. If I use [10,5] it works like a charm. But it does not work using a array variable name. What is wrong?

```
$dash = [10,5];
  "MultiLineString": [new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: "'.$a_Colour.'",
      width: "'.$a_gpx_line_width.'",
    lineDash: [10,5] // does work but $dash does not work but   
    })
  })]
};';
```

Comment: [Tour]. You also could say the error message so we can answer your question.

Comment: I'm tweeking PHP code and can not find the specific error.

Comment: You just say "it is not working." That isn't how you get answers. You say what is exactly going on. No explanation = No answer.

Comment: if i use for lineDash [10,5] i'm getting a nice multiline with the correct dash format. If I use $dask = [10,5] and then use $dash to assign to lineDash. I getting the map but no line at all. I do not see any error message

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I try to understand what I do wrong the array clearly contains to integer values. I need to vary the dashing by user input so I hope I can get it to take variable input. All the examples I can find are all in the format [int,int]

Comment: You code seems not to reproducible _as it_. Please update your code in order to it will be executable on our machines.
If I execute the PHP as it I have a parse error because of your "MultiLineString" part.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your php version, try to use

```
  $dash = array(10,5);
```

instead of

```
  $dash = [10,5];
```

Comment: That is just what I tried and both versions fail to produce the dotted line while [10,5] directly assigned to lineDash is working like a charm

Comment: Are you sure linedash takes an array? maybe it takes [10,5] as a string... try this: $dash = "[10,5]";

Comment: Yes I'm pretty sure and also the ol api says: 
lineDash Array.<number> | undefined

Answer (score 0):

Finaly I found the issue. It appears that the whole MultilineString need to passed as a string. So the code for the lineDash need to be:
***lineDash: ['.$dash[0].','.$dash[1].']***
which becomes: ***lineDash: [10,5]*** in the String Var